# ERROR: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found on Centos Linux 7.7 while installing R devtools

Tags: r, glibc, devtools, libstdc++

I have a VM running with Centos Linux 7.7.1908. Now I ant to install devtools in R with:

```
> install.packages("devtools")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/owner/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-xml2/00new/xml2/libs/xml2.so)
```

When doing: `strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC` it does not show GLIBCXX_3.4.20 (as expected according to the error). The anaconda version in contrast shows

```
$ strings /home/owner/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
[...]
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
[...]
```

My idea was now to force R to use the anaconda version instead of libstdc++ in lib64. I tried to add to PATH (it was already there) and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but no success here.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to add to PATH (it was already there) and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but no success here.

`PATH` has absolutely not effect on where the dynamic loader looks for libraries, but `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does, and should have worked.

If it didn't really work, it's likely because some intermediate shell script `unsets` that environment variable, *or* prepends `/usr/lib64` to it. You'll need to find that script, and fix it.